# Attaching AXLSX view to mail Rails Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, axlsx

According to the [GitHub Page](https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails) for the `axlsx` gem I should use this syntax to render a xlsx view to a file and attach it:

```
xlsx = render_to_string handlers: [:axlsx], formats: [:xlsx], template: "users/export", locals: {users: users}
attachments["Users.xlsx"] = {mime_type: Mime::XLSX, content: xlsx}
```

Here is my mail method:

```
xlsx = render_to_string(handlers: [:axlsx], formats: [:xlsx], template: 'v1/reports/reportxyz', params: {start_date: '2016-09-12', period: 'weekly'})
attachments["report.xlsx"] = {content: xlsx, mime_type: Mime::XLSX}
mail(to: "my@email.address", subject: "Report", format: "text")
```

However I get this error when I try and call the mailer method:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template layouts/mailer with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:xlsx], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:axlsx]}. Searched in:
  * "path/to/project/app/views"
```

Why is the `render_to_string` method affecting what the mailer view the mailer is trying to render? locgially I don't have a `mailer.xlsx.axlsx` file in my `app/views/layouts` folder but rather the `mailer.text.erb` I am trying to use as with other emails.

EDIT

I changed the render line to `xlsx = render_to_string(template: 'v1/reports/azamara_social', params: {start_date: '2016-09-12', period: 'weekly'})`

And now it seems to try and render the `xlsx` view but of course gets `nil:NilClass` errors when the `xlsx` view tries to reference instance variables defined in the reports controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it all came down to moving the controller code into a lib file. This way I call it in the controller to get the data if it needs to be rendered via web-requests as well as via the Mailer method where I recreate the `@variables` the view template is looking for.

Here is the finished salient parts of the report mailer method:

```
data = ReportUtils.get_data(args)
xlsx = render_to_string(template: 'path/to/report.xlsx', locals: {:@period => period, :@date_ranges => data[:date_ranges], :@data => data[:data]})
attachments["report.xlsx"] = {content: xlsx, mime_type: Mime::XLSX}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing layout: false? What versions of axlsx, axlsx_rails, rails, and rubyzip are you using?

Comment: This was the answer